# QSqlTableModel fetchMore() wildly inefficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, qt

Looking around, with QSqlTableModel, the way to get *all* rows out of a table is

```
select();
while( canFetchMore() ) {
    fetchMore();
}
```

The first select seems fine, but the fetchMore() seems to grab one row at a time.  I'm hammering the Sql server and a fetch of about 350 rows is taking up to a couple of seconds, not to mention wasting a bunch of CPU.

The Database is SQL-Server. Is there no better way?

Comment: Fetch more should be used with pagination, instead of downloading the whole table. You should display the first page and put a button to trigger fetch more...

Comment: I need the whole table -- it's not necessarily for display... I have to compare tables.  Looks like QSqlQueryModel will be better.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After some digging and help from a DBA, I can confirm that I get different behavior out of two different databases. Unfortunately, they are the same version of SQL Server, and both are using the ODBC Driver on Linux (written by Microsoft).  Under the sheets, one will select 256 rows, then each iteration of fetchMore() will select another 256 rows.  For the other one, select() and fetchMore() will only get one row at a time, and is causing all kinds of problems.

My solution is, unfortunately, is to pass QSqlQuery to a QSqlDatabase.